# ImageMagick create image with 2 lines

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

I recently tried imagemagick and wanted to ask how I create an image (.bmp file) which looks like this:

[image]

My current code looks like this:

```
convert -size 720x480 xc:blue \ -fill white -stroke black -strokewidth 0 -draw "line 5,20 95,20" \ myImage.bmp
```

But it creates this[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably go with this:

```
convert xc:black[720x480\!] -size 100x5 \
   \( xc:lime xc:blue -append -write MPR:stripe \) -geometry +165+400 -composite \
  MPR:stripe -geometry +295+400 -composite \
  MPR:stripe -geometry +425+400 -composite result.png
```

The *interesting* part is the second line where I create a lime green rectangle and a blue one the same size underneath (`-append`) and save that in an MPR (Magick Persistent Register) called `stripe`, then I re-use that to make each subsequent stripe.

Or this:

```
convert -size 720x480 xc:black -strokewidth 5 \
  -stroke lime                                \
  -draw "line 165,400 265,400" -draw "line 295,400 395,400" -draw "line 425,400 525,400" \
  -stroke blue                                \
  -draw "line 165,405 265,405" -draw "line 295,405 395,405" -draw "line 425,405 525,405" myImage.bmp
```

[image]

Comment: hi do I need those backslashes?

Comment: It deoends on your OS/shell. You do in `bash`.

Comment: COuld you explain why you do have 4 values I somehow got confused for example this 165,400 265,400

Comment: The `-draw line` command takes an X & Y value for the start of the line and another X & Y value for the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

You have some rubbish in your command but it has done what you asked it to - draw a black line on a blue background.

This should get you started:

```
convert -size 720x480 xc:black -strokewidth 5 -stroke green -fill none -draw "line 50,200 95,200" -stroke blue -draw "line 50,205 95,205" myImage.bmp
```